# Default User model throws error in laravel

Tags: php, class, laravel, model

The default model "User" in laravel throws error when I tried to use it. What I tried is,

```
$user = new User();
$user->email = Input::get('email');
$user->password = Hash::make(Input::get('password'));
$user->name = "Blah Blah";
$user->access_type = "admin";
$user->access_status = 1;
$user->save();
```

and the error thrown is

```
Symfony \ Component \ Debug \ Exception \ FatalErrorException

Call to undefined method User::save()
```

What is the issue? I also tried `User::all()` to retrieve the values, which also throws error `Call to undefined method User::all()`.

Update1:
Here is my model

```
use Illuminate\Auth\UserInterface;
use Illuminate\Auth\Reminders\RemindableInterface;

class User extends Eloquent implements UserInterface, RemindableInterface {

    /**
     * The database table used by the model.
     *
     * @var string
     */
    protected $table = 'users';

    /**
     * The attributes excluded from the model's JSON form.
     *
     * @var array
     */
    protected $hidden = array('password');

    /**
     * Get the unique identifier for the user.
     *
     * @return mixed
     */
    public function getAuthIdentifier()
    {
        return $this->getKey();
    }

    /**
     * Get the password for the user.
     *
     * @return string
     */
    public function getAuthPassword()
    {
        return $this->password;
    }

    /**
     * Get the token value for the "remember me" session.
     *
     * @return string
     */
    public function getRememberToken()
    {
        return $this->remember_token;
    }

    /**
     * Set the token value for the "remember me" session.
     *
     * @param  string  $value
     * @return void
     */
    public function setRememberToken($value)
    {
        $this->remember_token = $value;
    }

    /**
     * Get the column name for the "remember me" token.
     *
     * @return string
     */
    public function getRememberTokenName()
    {
        return 'remember_token';
    }

    /**
     * Get the e-mail address where password reminders are sent.
     *
     * @return string
     */
    public function getReminderEmail()
    {
        return $this->email;
    }

}
```

Update2:
I tried writing another model names and class name as `Users`, which works perfectly. But for authentication, it must be the `User` table right?

Comment: Can you please add your User model code to the question..

Comment: I have't changed anything much other than the table name in default file. I'll update it.

Comment: Can you try $user = new User;  ...  (without function brackets)

Comment: I think there is some other default function which overrides this model. Is there any way to debug that thing? It's a fresh installation of laravel and this is my only function. So it's not my mistake.

Comment: Try extends \Eloquent ...Looks like Eloquent is not extended..

Comment: Do you have another class somewhere called User?

Comment: @ChintanParekh tried that one. No hope.

Comment: @DamienPirsy It's a fresh installation and this is the only function I have. Must be some error by laravel itsef.

Comment: I tried writing another model names and class name as Users, which works perfectly. But for authentication, it must be the User table right?

Comment: What do you mean by for authentication? (btw. if it works with Users model then it should work with User model, you definitely have some very small mistake)

Comment: @ChintanParekh It has to work. But it is not. What I mean is the laravel in built authentication function. It checks the credentials from the `User` class right?

Comment: Yes, but there is a way around..you can open app->config->auth.php   and then change the table name to the required table (Reference: http://laravel-recipes.com/recipes/12)

Comment: However, I still don't understand your problem with User model and not with Users model. You might be missing a small thing.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Still didn't received any answer to my question. Anyways now I'm running it using the new model named `Users` with the same doubt in mind.

Answer (score 1):

The reason for the issue is autoloader load wrong "User" model. Please have a look at the "/vendor/composer/autoload_classmap.php" file. Inside the return array value for the key "User" must be `$baseDir . '/app/models/User.php`

```
return array(
...,
'User' => $baseDir . '/app/models/User.php',
...,
);
```

Answer (score 0):

Maybe User is a reserved word, just give the model another name say UserTbl